# How can I change the svn diff patch number of context lines?

Tags: svn

What I'm exactly looking for is: using `svn diff`, how to print more lines above and below the new code which is being added?

By default it will print some lines which are unchanged (both below/above the new code which is changed).

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: How can i achieve this using only diff command? diff between two directories ?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37154949/2977520) is much better and works if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 25):

If you are on linux, tell your [diff tool](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_diff.htm) how many lines to include into result, for example 10:

```
svn diff --diff-cmd=diff -x -U10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this within svn diff itself, which works on Windows too. Say you want 20 lines of context, you can do this:

`svn diff -x -U20`

Taken from [svn diff how to only show changed line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152186/svn-diff-how-to-only-show-changed-line/37154949#37154949)