# svn diff how to only show changed line

Tags: svn

When I used "svn diff en.lua ", I get this result:

```
 num="Amount",
 all="All",
 class="Quality",
-own="Have",
+own="Have2",
 paper="Specs",
 piece="Shard",
 not_enough=" not enough",
```

but I only want to see this

```
-own="Have",
+own="Have2",
```

I'm wondering which parameter should I use for "svn diff"?

Comment: You **must** do not want diff without context

Answer (score 7):

At least with svn 1.9, you can use `svn diff -x -U0`. I'm unsure whether the option is available in earlier versions. This does not seem to be documented in the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.extensions), however the command line documentation shows:

```
$svn help diff
[...]
  -x [--extensions] ARG    : Specify differencing options for external diff or
                             internal diff or blame. Default: '-u'. Options are
                             separated by spaces. Internal diff and blame take:
                               -u, --unified: Show 3 lines of unified context
                               -b, --ignore-space-change: Ignore changes in
                                 amount of white space
                               -w, --ignore-all-space: Ignore all white space
                               --ignore-eol-style: Ignore changes in EOL style
                               -U ARG, --context ARG: Show ARG lines of context
                               -p, --show-c-function: Show C function name
```

Comment: My svn version is 1.8.11

Comment: This answer needs a LOT more attention. I've been using the workarounds  for Linux for ages which involves invoking a third-party diff program. This is the answer that most people, especially on Windows, are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for any SVN version:

```
svn diff some_file.extension | sed -n -e '/@@/,$p' | grep -vE "^( |@@)"
```

Explanation:

- The `sed` command skips header.
- The `grep` command skips non-matched lines (which are prefixed with space) and changes info.

So you should only be left with lines starting with a single `+` or `-`.

Comment: this combined with the other answer -x -U0 really made my day