# How to get the full context diff of two revisions of svn in a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, svn, tortoisesvn

I am writing a python script using svn commands to print the full context change log(full files with the changes indicated) of 2 svn revisions on a file.

I have two commits on a svn repo and I need the diff of these 2 revisions.
For this I can get it using

```
svn diff -r <rev1>:<rev2>
```

But the problem is that this only give few line in context of the change. For example, If i have a file of 100 lines and I made change in line number 50, this will show me the changes in line 50, and say 5-7 lines above and below it.

What My need is, is a command(or some other way) to show me the full file with the changes shown only in line 50.

Also tried using suggestion mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291513/how-can-i-change-the-svn-diff-patch-number-of-context-lines), however it did not seem to work out for me with the scenario in hand.

Any help on this context is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the command that you provided the link for:

`svn diff --diff-cmd=diff -x -U10`

Here the `--diff-cmd` means that you are going to use a third party tool for doing difference. And the third party tool you are going to use is `diff`.
So first you need to see whether the `diff` tool is installed in your system and is on your path variable.

You can check that out by typing the following in the command promt or terminal.
`diff --help`
[image: diff help in cmd]

For your case as you need the entire files you should try something like the following command:

`svn diff -r 34:35 --diff-cmd=diff -x -y > somefile.txt`

Here you are asking svn to diff revision 34 and 35, but use an external diff tool named `diff`. With `-x` you are telling that you pass the flag `-y` to this external tool and store the output in a text file.

The `-y` flag tell the external diff tool to do a side by side comparison and output the data in two columns.

The text file will look something like this. This will be a very long file as it has the entirety of all the files that have been changed.
[image: Example Some Text File]

Comment: I tried your suggestion, however it gives me the following error : svn: E720087: Can't start process 'diff': The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: Also, what is the external diff tool that you have used for the above ?

Comment: I am using the following diff
`diff (GNU diffutils) 2.8.7`
`Written by Paul Eggert, Mike Haertel, David Hayes, Richard Stallman, and Len Tower.`
`Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: You can try removing the revision command and get the diff between the current working directory and the commit version.
`svn diff --diff-cmd=diff -x -y`

Comment: But the problem is, i need the diff between two revisions only, not the working copy.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share the screen shot for your error?? Cause this seems to be working for me... Only possibility revision number might not exists...

Comment: It is working now, once I am using the diff tool that you mentioned. Thanks ! One more thing, is it possible to have one instance of the file(the newer version) to be printed with the changes indicated, rather than both instances?

Comment: Got it, we can do it using the -u switch in the same external diff agent.

Comment: Can you type the entire command? I am not able to get the same.

Comment: svn diff -r <rev1>:<rev2> --diff-cmd=diff -x -u1000 > somefile.txt